# Why does my list get assigned the value of "none" when using a reverse operations?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and I am trying to create a program the will tell a user if the word they enter is a palindrome. When I execute my code, it outputs the following:

> Please enter a word. I will tell you if that word is a palindrome or not: *hannah*
>
> Please enter a word. I will tell you if that word is a palindrome or not: hannah
>   This word is not a palindrome
>
> **None**['n', 'a', 'h']
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Im not sure why the list within cal_tableRev is saving as "none". Any ideas on how I might fix this would be a great help!

```
user_input = input("Please enter a word. I will tell you if that word is a palindrome or not: ").lower()
cal_table1 = []
cal_table2 = []


for letter in user_input:
    cal_table1.append(letter)

inputSize = len(cal_table1)
Calsize = inputSize / 2

if inputSize % 2 != 0:
    print("The word has an odd number of letters and, therefore, it is not a palindrome. Please enter a new word")

for letters in cal_table1[0:int(Calsize)]:
    cal_table2.append(letters)

cal_tableRev = str(cal_table2.reverse())

frontHalf = str(cal_tableRev)
backHalf = str(cal_table2)
calulated_word = str(frontHalf) + str(backHalf)

if user_input == calulated_word:
    print("This word is a palindrome")
else:
    print("This word is not a palindrome")

print(calulated_word)
```

Comment: Your indentation does not look correct on the 2nd and 3rd lines of the code your posted.  Please insure the code you are posting is what you are using.

Comment: Made the correction, sorry the formatting was wrong in my post but was correct in my IDE when I was attempting to run the script.

Comment: Also aren't words like `wow` and `tenet` palindromes even though the contain a odd number of letters?

Comment: Correct, but for the purpose of this program, I only want to allow words with even numbers. Sorry if its a bit misleading..

Comment: Be wary that `list.reverse()`doesn't return anything as it reverse the list in place (see [mutable-sequence-types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types))

Comment: It looks like you are doing a lot of work that some built in python functions can make easier.  For example `backwards=''.join(reversed(word))` then execute `word == backwards` to see if work is a palindrome.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! I will try that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The function reverse() reverses a given list but returns the value None which you then assigned to cal_tableRev
try:

```
cal_tableRev = copy.deepcopy(cal_table2)
cal_tableRev.reverse() #reversing without assigning the None value
cal_tableRev=str(cal_tableRev)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are doing a lot of work python can make easier for you.  Take a look at these commands I ran in a python console:

```
>>> word='tenet'
>>> backwards=''.join(reversed(word))
>>> word == backwards
True

>>> word='pizza'
>>> backwards=''.join(reversed(word))
>>> word == backwards
False

>>> word
'pizza'
>>> backwards
'azzip'
```